# Volume of $x^2+y^2\leq4,\quad z=2+x^2+y^2,\quad z\geq-1$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals, volume

**Find the volume of the solid defined by $$x^2+y^2\leq4,\quad z=2+x^2+y^2,\quad z\geq-1.$$**

---

I found the intersection of surfaces:

$$S\equiv\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2&=4\\
2+x^2+y^2&=z\\
z&=-1
\end{cases}
\equiv
\begin{cases}
x^2+y^2&=4\\
2+4&\neq-1\\
z&=-1.
\end{cases}$$

The surfaces are not cut, and therefore do not define a volume in space. Is it right?

Thanks!

Comment: Your solid is the underside of a paraboloid starting at $z=-1$

Comment: "$z\ge -1$" seems strange when "$z= 2+ x^2+ y^2$" already requires that z be at least 2.

Comment: @user247327 It's only strange if you treat the $z$ in $z=2+x^2+y^2$ as the same $z$ in $z\ge -1$. They aren't actually the same number $z$; rather, they represent a surface and a region, respectively, not a system of equations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**FALSE.** Not all three have to intersect; notice that the surfaces $x^2+y^2=4$ and $z=x^2+y^2+2$ intersect, and the surfaces $x^2+y^2=4$ and $z= -1$ intersect, forming a cylinder-like volume with a circular base and a concave paraboloid-shaped "lid."

You may calculate the volume by converting to polar coordinates and considering the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi} \int_{0}^{2} (r^2+3)\cdot r\space dr\space d\theta$$

Comment: Thanks! Can I ask why $0\leq\rho\leq\color{red}4$? Also, how do you find the integrand?

Comment: @manooooh Sorry, $r$ should range from $0$ to $2$. This is because $r^2=x^2+y^2\le 4$.

Comment: @manooooh The integrand is $z-(-1)=x^2+y^2+3=r^2+3$, ranging from the flat surface $z=-1$ to the parabolic "lid" surface $z=2+x^2+y^2$.

Comment: Ok, two more questions: 1) why $z-(-1)$ if $z\geq-1$? It should not be $z+1=\cdots$?

Comment: $z-(-1)$ is the same as $z+1$. The integrand should be the difference in the heights of the two surfaces, which is why I wrote it as $z-(-1)$. What is your second question?

Comment: 2) The condition $z\geq-1$ does not say anything about the projection should be cut and, therefore, the range of $\theta$ change (not $0\leq\theta\leq2\pi$), right? Because when proyecting into $xy$-plane we are in $z=0$, not $z\geq-1$?

Comment: OMG I am a totally disaster, yes, $z-(-1)=z+1$, sorry.

Comment: @manooooh Right, the conditions $z=x^2+y^2+2$ and $z\ge -1$ do not affect the values of $\theta$. If instead we had $z=f(x,y)$ and $z\ge g(x,y)$, the integrand would be $f(x,y)-g(x,y)$ with $\theta$ and $r$ on the same bounds, provided that $f(x,y)\ge g(x,y)$ for all $x,y$ in the region. The condition $x^2+y^2\le 4$ determines the bounds during the switch to cylindrical coordinates.

Comment: Last question (*sorry!*): if you convert the integral to polar coordinates, why you don't add the jacobian, i.e., why you don't add a $\rho$ in the integrand?

Comment: @manooooh Gah! That one is my mistake; I forgot the $r$. Forgive me!